# How to correct -> cannot convert sockaddr** to sockaddr* for arg 5 of recvfrom()

Tags: c, compiler-errors, udp

I get the above compiler error.

I am opening one send and one receive socket in my main,   Calling a function passing socket handles and other socket info to the function so I can do the send and receive in that function.

here's a shortened and incomplete version of the code.

```
Main()
{
sockaddr_in _remote_address;
sockaddr_in address;
sockaddr sender_address;

temp_build(6, _rsckt, _sckt, &_remote_address, &sender_address, LOGGING);

{

void function (int msg_id, int rsckt, int sckt, struct sockaddr_in* _remote_address, struct sockaddr* sender_address, int logflag)

**Here’s the compiler error**

cannot convert  ‘sockaddr**’  to  ‘sockaddr*’  for argument ‘5’  to  ‘ssize_t recvfrom(int, void*,size_t, int, sockaddr* socklen_t*)’
```

Comment: Where is your actual call to `recvfrom`?

Comment: Are you by any chance passing `&sender_address` to `recvfrom`?

Comment: Yes I am passing &sender_address to recvfrom.  Should it just be sender_address,  if so, that compiles but then I cannot print out the contents of _remote_address or sender_address.    How should I dereference those two structs to print the contents? Because after it compiles, neither the send or receive work.   If I leave send and receive in the main, they work fine

Comment: show actual code or it's impossible to know. argument 5 is (socklen_t*)